# Regular graphs has exactly one main eigenvalue

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

An eigenvalue $\lambda_{1} $ is said to be a main eigenvalue if it has an associated eigenvector $x_{1} $ whose sum of entries is nonzero, in other words the projection of $e $, the all ones vector, onto the eigenspace $W_{\lambda_{1}}$ corresponding to $\lambda_{1} $ should be nonzero.

A graph $G $ is $k $-regular if each of its vertices is of degree $k $.

It is known that a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices is said to be $k$-regular graph if and only if its corresponding adjacency matrix has exactly one main eigenvalue.

Now I'm trying to prove the sufficient condition, i.e. a graph $G $ with one main eigenvalue is $k $-regular.
I notice that the projection of $e $ onto the rest of the eigenspaces other than $W_{\lambda_{1}} $ is zero (since there exists only one maineigenvalue).
Moreover, $e$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis of the eigenspaces corresponding to the $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},...,\lambda_{n} $ eigenvalues of $G $, hence, $e= proj_{W_{1}=span (x_{1})}(e)x_{1}= c x_{1}$ with c a nonzero constant.
So $G $ is regular.

Is my proof true? Thank you

My explicit proof:
Let $\{\lambda_{1}^{(m_{1})}, \lambda_{2}^{(m_{2})},..., \lambda_{s}^{(m_{s})}\}$ be the spectrum of $G$ counting multiplicities, and for $j=1, 2,..., s$, let $\{w_{j1},w_{j2},...,w_{jm_{j}} \}$ be the eigenvectors corersponding to $\lambda_{j}$ hence the eigenspace corresponding to each eigenvalue $\lambda_{j}$ is $W_{j}= span(w_{j1},..., w_{jm_{j}})$ i.e. $(w_{j1},..., w_{jm_{j}})$ makes up the basis of $W_{j}$. We consider $\lambda_{1}$ to be the only main eigenvalue of $G$ (so $m_{1}=1$) and $w_{11}$ is its only corresponding eigenvector whose sum of entries is nonzero.
    \Thus by Lemma 1.4.1, $proj_{W_{1}=span(w_{11})}(\textbf{e})= (w_{11}, \textbf{e})w_{11} \ne 0$. We deduce for $j=2,...,s,$ $ proj_{W_{j}}(\textbf{e})= 0$.\
    Now, \textbf{e} can be written as a linear combination of basis of the eigenspaces $W_{j}$ for $j=1,...,s$, thus $\textbf{e}= \sum_{j=1}^{s}\sum_{k=1}^{m_{j}}(w_{jk}, \textbf{e})w_{jk}=\underbrace{(w_{11}, \textbf{e})}_{= c \ne 0} w_{11}+
  \sum_{j=2}^{s}\underbrace{proj_{W_{j}}(\textbf{e})}_{0}=  cw_{11}$

Therefore, $A(G)\textbf{e}= A(G)cw_{11}= cA(G)w_{11}= c\lambda_{1}w_{11}= \lambda_{1}cw_{11}= \lambda_{1} \textbf{e}$.

Comment: You appear to be assuming $G$ is connected; this is reasonable but should be explicit.

Comment: Yes, G is connected. I wrote the proof explicitly, just added it in the body. But I have a problem. I reached that $A(G)\textbf{e}= \lambda_{1}\textbf{e}$ but I cannot deduce that $G$ is $\lambda_{1}$ regular unless I know that $\lambda_{1}$ is an integer. Can I know? or is this may not be the correct approach?